# What's the name of this flower with red colored leaf?

Tags: identification

I found this stock photo from [dreamstime.com](http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-photo-orange-flower-image29629535) listed as "Firecracker plant" or "Flor Cebacia".

[image: Unknown plant]

Answer (score 2):

Could be a single flower from the African Tulip tree, Spathodea campanulata, though it looks more like a photograph of a painting of the flower than the actual flower. The flowers on this tree grow in clusters, not individually as shown here, and there aren't any leaves or other clues as to ID to be 100% sure, so I'd have to say 95% certainty. Considered an invasive plant in some hotter regions of Australia, its a tropical plant which is highly sensitive to cool or cold temperatures. Usually evergreen, can be grown in other places such as California, where it might behave as a deciduous tree because of cooler temperatures.